# advanced strategies to aggregate big data to generate tableau dashboards?

Tags: sql, database, bigdata, aggregate, tableau-api

So i've been developing data tools for a few years, and I'm a bit stuck on a large project. Say I have roughly 500 million records and 15 columns, in this format:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| customer_id | group | price | color | region |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 123         | a     | 12    | red   | north  |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 234         | c     | 11    | red   | south  |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 456         | c     | 54    | blue  | east   |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I want to build a simple dashboard that answers every possible question using every column. That is to say, I want every possible combination of metrics from each DIM/FACT in this table, such as:

Distinct customers in group c that are blue from east region.
Distinct customers in groups a+c that are red from south+north region.
Sum of total price by group by region.
Sum of total price for group c that is any color for north region.
Sum of total price for all regions.

If I were to just aggregate the sums of prices, I could group by all my DIMs for each FACT. But the problem gets a little complex when I start using distinct functions to count customer_ids as a FACT. For example, Customer_ids can exist in multiple groups, so If i count distinct customer_ids by group, i will have a larger total sum of customers than if i only count distinct customer ids.

So my question becomes, how can I build a dynamic dashboard to answer all of these potential combinations of questions without using the entire 500 million records? pre-aggregation seems impossible.

Comment: Have you considered using OLAP and then use it in tableau? It's useful especially when there is big data.

Comment: @barker . . . Pre-aggregation is very challenging when you are using distinct counts.

Comment: my data is stored in OLAP - REDSHIFT on aws. So I was thinking of not using an extract, and just pausing the tableau queries to execute on command back on redshift, then fetching the data to present in tableau.